# Json не содержит список зависимых объектов

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой: после конвертирования объекта в JSON, я не вижу в нем списка зависимых объектов, считанных  из БД. У меня есть два класса `AutoService` и `Service`. У одного автосервиса может быть несколько услуг, то есть отношение OneToMany. В результате чего в классе AutoService в поле храниться список услуг

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "autoServiceId")
private List<Service> services;
```

Для конвертации в JSON использую `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

Ниже будет представлен код названных классов.

Класс `AutoService`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AutoRate")
public class AutoService {

    public AutoService() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "serviceName", nullable = false)
    private String serviceName;

    @Column(name = "imageURL", nullable = false)
    private String imageURL;

    @Column(name = "mapCoordinate", nullable = false)
    private String mapCoordinate;

    @Column(name = "websiteURL", nullable = false)
    private String websiteURL;

    @Column(name = "phoneNumber", nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "autoServiceId")
    private List<Service> services;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public String getMapCoordinate() {
        return mapCoordinate;
    }

    public String getWebsiteURL() {
        return websiteURL;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Класc Service

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Service")
public class Service {

    public Service() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "serviceId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long serviceId;

    @Column(name = "serviceName", nullable = false)
    private String serviceName;

    @Column(name = "category", nullable = false)
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private int price;

    @Column(name = "autoServiceId", nullable = false)
    private long autoServiceId;

    public long getId() {
        return serviceId;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }


    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public long getAutoServiceId() {
        return autoServiceId;
    }
}
```

В результате получаю следующий JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "serviceName": "SpeedyName",
    "imageURL": "Url for speedy",
    "mapCoordinate": "123123 44121 ",
    "websiteURL": "speedy.com",
    "phoneNumber": "1231251"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "serviceName": "Другой сервис",
    "imageURL": "Урл для второго сервиса",
    "mapCoordinate": "123 12фывфы",
    "websiteURL": "другойсервис.ком",
    "phoneNumber": "12312333"
  }
]
```

Список зависимых услуг для каждого сервиса отсутствует. Может быть мне не хватает какой-либо аннотации ? Прошу помощи с данной проблемой.

Comment: а где вы этот JSON получаете?

Comment: для тестирования postman использую

Comment: то есть у вас есть еще и `Controller`? а почему его тут не видно?

Comment: геттер-то для сервисов сделайте, джексон только через черную рефлексию сейчас может в поле заглянуть

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить `@JsonManagedReference` к полю `services` в классе `AutoService`

Comment: Сделал, как вы и сказали, но почему то JSON не изменился ((

Comment: @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "autoServiceId")
    private List<Service> services;

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй как в данном примере

```
public class User {
    public int id;
    public String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    public List<Item> userItems; } 

public class Item {
    public int id;
    public String itemName;

    @JsonManagedReference
    public User owner; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в отсутствии геттера на `List<Services>`